# Resizing element by dragging

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a calendar-like view that shows a table with one column per day of the week ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vf38.png)). Each row represents a specific thing that can be booked for a time. The idea is now that a booking can be extended by dragging the outer edge to the next day in the table, or shortened the same way. The active booking has a span on each side of the cell that is supposed to be the handle for dragging.

My main problem now is that the usual drag & drop features in browsers don't seem to fit my situation. I don't want to drag something and drop it anywhere else, I just want to drag to extend the item.

Is this still something that can be done with the usual HTML5 drag&drop feature or some generic drag&drop library? Or is there any other way to achieve this? Any pointers on how to approach this problem?

I'm using React for this, which might make some solutions difficult to integrate if they manipulate the DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

ummm not sure what to do here , I thinks its unlikely the link will change soon , I can describe the repo 'Allows individual or group selection of items using the mouse. Click and drag to lasso multiple items, hold the cmd/ctrl key to select non-adjacent items'.  I can  briefly describe what the lib code does:  uses keydown, keyup and mousedown listeners to create an overlay and detect covered nodes in the DOM .